# ASP.Net MVC and WebApi authentication using Identity server

Tags: claims-based-identity, identityserver3

I am new to Identity server and wants to secure my two apps (MVC, Webapi) using it.
I have seen the example where we can invoke the webapi from MVC action method and SetBearerToken that was issued to the the MVC application. I am referring the below sample:

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html

This is typical example of server to server communication where we are using access token issued to the MVC app for Web api.

In the same scenario, I want to call webapi from Javascript client(fro ex Angular or any one) using same access token.

"I want to pass the the access token issued to the MVC application to call WebAPI from JavaScript"

How can I utilize the token that was issued to my MVC application from the JavaScript client?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They should be treated as different client in my opinion, I guess they are different site? For your Javascript client you should be able to find example [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients) , you can use the javascript lib that provided in the example or write one yourself

Once you get the token, then you can call your API using AJAX, where you might face CORS problem if your webapi is on a different domain, well...that is different topic.

Hope that helps

Comment: so, what about the application flow: 

1: User will login into webapp using UseOpenIdConnect 

2. Identity server will open the login page, authenticate the user and store the the token in cookie

3. Now, if we want to access web api we will get the acctess token from identity server again

4. Pass the token in header(bearer token) to access web api

What do you think?

Comment: hi there, sorry for late rely, for 3) , if you want to call API on server side of your webapp, you can get it from ClaimsPrincipal because access token should be a claim, an example can be found here:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/MVC%20Authentication/EmbeddedMvc/Controllers/CallApiController.cs

Comment: Yes, you are correct. We can easily get the the access token at server side from ClaimPrincipal. But, my requirement is different. I dont want to access the web Api through server , I want to directly access it from any JS client like AngularJS or something else..So keeping this in mind what would you suggest?

Comment: To be more specific, once I am authenticated from my MVC app i want to access my Web Api but without routing through MVC App (directly from JS client)

Comment: Sorry I think I've now understood your question better - your JS client is actually on your MVC page. Is any reason that you don't want to make server call into your webapi? Isn't it more secure to be called on server side? you want your web api to be protected right? or if you really want to be able to be called from JS client, maybe considering to create a endpoint in your MVC app which calls into webapi and itself exposes to JS client?

Comment: Yes, I can create an endpoint in MVC app to call the WebApi but this is creating extra hop in my application. JSclient->MVC App->WebApi. I want to get rid of this extra hop (MVC app). So sometimes I want to access webapi through MVC app  and sometimes directly from JS client.